# Android CoordinatorLayout Behaviour with complex layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

I have a simple layout that is a `CoordinatorLayout` containing a `Toolbar` in an `AppBarLayout` and a `RecyclerView`. To allow for a progress bar while content is loaded into the `RecyclerView` I've wrapped it in a `FrameLayout` alongside a `ProgressBar` which I've included from another file. When the content is loading the `ProgressBar` is set to `VISIBLE` and when it's finished it's set to `GONE`, showing the `RecyclerView`. I'd like to use a `ScrollingViewBehavior` so that when I scroll my `RecyclerView` the `Toolbar` is hidden. I've tried adding it to the `FrameLayout` and the `RecyclerView` and neither seems to work.

What do I have to do to get the behavior I am looking for? Do I need to make a new `ViewGroup` or something like that in order to show/hide the `ProgressBar` and define a new `Behavior` for that, or is there something simpler?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view" />

        <include layout="@layout/progress_circle" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/floating_action_button"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost the same setup you do, but I've included two progress bars. One appears when the activity is loaded, and covers the whole thing. The second one appears on a swipe refresh and only replaces the RecyclerView (well, actually the RecyclerView's parent SwipeRefreshLayout).

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <include layout="@layout/loading_progress"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_landing_page"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/loading_progress"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/landing_page_top_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my progress bar is just:

```
<ProgressBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

When it's time to show the progress bar I set it to View.VISIBLE and the SwipeRefreshLayout (or the CoordinatorLayout for when the Activity is loaded) to View.GONE. Then reverse the VISIBLE and GONE when the data is loaded.

Comment: Oh this makes sense since `CoordinatorLayout` is basically just a `FrameLayout`. I'll try this out and get back to you.